# Rewriting conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider two discrete random variables $(X,Y)$ taking values in $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$.

Consider a set $\mathcal{A}\equiv \mathcal{A}_x\times \mathcal{A}_y$, where $\mathcal{A}_x\subseteq \mathcal{X}$  and $\mathcal{A}_y\subseteq \mathcal{Y}$.

Further, consider another discrete random variable $W$ such that
$$
(*) \quad \text{If $(X,Y)$ take values in $\mathcal{A}$, then $W=2$}
$$

**Claim:** Take two real numbers $(x,y)\in \mathcal{A}$. I want to show that
$$
Pr(Y=y| X=x)=Pr(Y=y| X=x,W=2) 
$$

Could you check whether this proof is correct? This claim seems to me surprising and so I want to check whether I'm making mistakes.

**My attempt of proof:**

$$
Pr(Y=y| X=x)=\frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x)}{Pr(X=x)}= \frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x)}{\sum_{y\in \mathcal{A}_y}Pr(X=x, Y=y)}=\overbrace{=}^{\text{by (*)}} \frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x, W=2)}{\sum_{y\in \mathcal{A}_y}Pr(X=x, Y=y, W=2)} =\frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x| W=2)Pr(W=2)}{\sum_{y\in \mathcal{A}_y}Pr(X=x, Y=y| W=2) Pr(W=2)}=\frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x|W=2)}{\sum_{y\in \mathcal{A}_y}Pr(Y=y, X=x|W=2)}= \frac{Pr(Y=y, X=x|W=2)}{Pr(X=x|W=2)} =Pr(Y=y| X=x,W=2) 
$$

Comment: I don't think is correct. $Pr(Y=y|X=y)$ from left side does not include 'for any $(x,y) \in A$'. You put it as a separate statement, which is ok as description, but it is not ok to continue with an equal. Your proof for example does not include that assertion. A way to fix it is to include it, so in the left side you would have $Pr(Y=y,(x,y) \in A|X=x)$ which is equivalent with $Pr(Y=y,W=2|X=x)$ I think.